# Group the text nodes as well as element nodes based on few starting text

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest to make group the text() + element node based on few text formats like (Fig.|Figs.|Figure|Table|Tables). If these citations text starts with and ends-with parenthesis like (,[,{,),],} signs, grouping should enclose the parenthesis too, otherwise Fig|Table word + Xref element(s) to be grouped within <col1>***</col1>.

These grouping should applicable any text() nodes except under 'Refs' element.

**Input:**

```
<root>
    <Para>The citations are like (Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</Para>
    <Para>The <b>citations are like (Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</b></Para>
    <Extract>The citations are like (Figs. <xref refID="f1">1</xref> and <xref refID="f2">2</xref>).</Extract>
    <DispQuote>The citations are like (Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref>).</DispQuote>
    <Para1>The citations are like (Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref>; Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</Para1>
    <Para2>The citations are like (analysation of Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</Para2>
    <Para>The citations are like (explained in Figs. <xref refID="f1">1</xref> and <xref refID="f2">2</xref>).</Para>
    <Para>The citations are like (Chapter 1 and 3 are explained in Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref>).</Para>
    <Refs>The citations are like (Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</Refs>
</root>
```

**XSLT2:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Para">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:call-template name="tempCrossRef1"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tempCrossRef1">
    <!--xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\([ ]+)|([\+])|([=])|([%])|([/])|([\[])|([\]])"-->
    <!-- (Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>) -->
    <!--xsl:analyze-string select="node()" regex="\(Fig. ">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="following-sibling::node()[2][parent::*/name()='xref']">
                    <col><xsl:apply-templates select="."/></col>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string-->
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with(., 'Fig.')">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="self::node()[ends-with(., 'Fig.')]" group-adjacent="boolean(self::xref)">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <p1>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                            </p1>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref">
    <xref>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xref>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<root>
    <Para>The citations are like <col1>(Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>)</col1>.</Para>
    <Para>The <b>citations are like <col1>(Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>)</col1>.</b></Para>
    <Para>The citations are like <col1>(Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>)</col1>.</Para>
    <Extract>The citations are like <col1>(Figs. <xref refID="f1">1</xref> and <xref refID="f2">2</xref>)</col1>.</Extract>
    <DispQuote>The citations are like <col1>(Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref>)</col1>.</DispQuote>
    <Para1>The citations are like <col1>(Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref>; Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>)</col1>.</Para1>
    <Para2>The citations are like (analysation of <col1>Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref></col1>).</Para2>
    <Para>The citations are like (explained in <col1>Figs. <xref refID="f1">1</xref> and <xref refID="f2">2</xref></col1>).</Para>
    <Para>The citations are like (Chapter 1 and 3 are explained in <col1>Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref></col1>).</Para>
    <Refs>The citations are like (Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</Refs><!-- Within this element, grouping not required-->
</root>
```

Comment: Mixed text with elements is difficult to handle so one approach is usual a two step one where the first step transforms the text being a "marker" into an element, the second step can then use `for-each-group group-starting-with/end` or `group-adjacent` on the generated marker elements. Even then it is not an easy task if the content can be nested.

Comment: Yes Sir, I achieved as suggested with 2 XSLTs and Perl Regular expressions. But in some areas Perl not applicable, required only XSLTs scripts.

Comment: I have tried to implement this at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcow but the input `<Para1>The citations are like (Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref>; Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</Para1>` is not handled correctly as there is the `(Tables` as well as the `Fig.` text transformed to a `start` element and that way the `group-starting-witn/ending-with` does not give the result you have posted. This raises the general question, can there be several tables or figures in the same parent element and do they always have to be wrapped together?

Comment: Sir, great answer, `can there be several tables or figures in the same parent element and do they always have to be wrapped together?`, sir these formats are very rare. Thanks a lot for solving this formats. Please post the suggestion in answer block. I need to accept this great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt using two steps, the first transforms any of the patterns `[(]?(Fig\.|Figs\.|Figure|Table[s]?)` into `start` elements and the end patterns `[)]` into `end` elements, the second steps then tries to use `group-starting-with/ending-with` to wrap such content into `col1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="start-patterns" as="xs:string">[(]?(Fig\.|Figs\.|Figure|Table[s]?)</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="end-patterns" as="xs:string">[)]</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:mode name="text-to-elements" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="root/*[not(self::Refs)][matches(., $start-patterns)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="text-to-elements" as="node()*">
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="text-to-elements"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="$text-to-elements" group-starting-with="start">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::start">
                      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="end">
                          <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::end]">
                                  <col1>
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                  </col1>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                              </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:for-each-group>                      
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="start | end">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="text-to-elements">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$start-patterns}">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <start>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </start>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$end-patterns}">
                  <xsl:matching-substring>
                      <end>
                          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                      </end>                      
                  </xsl:matching-substring>
                  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
              </xsl:analyze-string>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcow, this approach seems to produce the wanted result for your posted input, except the for element

```
<Para1>The citations are like (Tables <xref refID="t1">1</xref> and <xref refID="t2">2</xref>; Fig. <xref refID="f1">1</xref>).</Para1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your great method to solve text-node grouping.